# In Drupal 7 how do I check if a node author has a certain role?

Tags: nodes, theming

Specifically, I have custom node.tpl.php called node--directory.tpl.php works great.
Now how do find out if the node author has the role 'premium_user',  so that node will have premium style features.
I have seen a post about checking the current user for a role:

```
global $user;

if (in_array('authenticated user', $user->roles)) {
     //do fancy style stuff here
}
```

I want to do the same for $uid (in node.tpl.php it says that is variable for the user id of the node author).
Any help appreciated.
Thanks
Frank

Answer (score 0):

`global $user` will give you the information about currently logged in user not about the node author.

To get the node author, you should use the $uid variable which is available in the [node template](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7). Below is the sample code(untested) for checking the author's role,

```
$author = user_load($uid);
if (in_array('premium_user', $author->roles)) {
  //do fancy style stuff here
}
```

Comment: That code crash with 'parse error'. I modified it as follows: 
        <?php 
  $author = user_load($uid);
  if (in_array('premium_user', $author->roles)): ?> 
  <div style="width:400px;height:400px;border:2px solid black;">
  <?php endif; ?>
 It doesn't throw an error but doesn't work either :( It is not returning TRUE in the if statement, because when check view source the <Div is not there.

Comment: Found this  https://drupal.org/node/1619504  Role id's are now (Drupal 7) machine readable strings. No underscore required. Thanks, works now :))

Answer (score 0):

You can use this custom function. Just place this it in a custom module, or in your **template.php** file :

```
function user_has_role($role, $user = null) {
  if ($user == NULL) {
    global $user;
  }

  if (is_array($user->roles) && in_array($role, array_values($user->roles))) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

You can use like this :

```
// How to use it for current logged in user
$role = 'myrole';
if (user_has_role($role)) {
  // Do something
}

// How to use it for x user
$role = 'myrole';
$user = user_load($uid);
if (user_has_role($role, $user)) {
  // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more granular approach, recommend checking for permissions using [user_access()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_access/7) instead of roles.

You'll have to implement your own permissions but it's much flexible to control which role has which permissions in the future.